# sed command creation via shell script - quotes and sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm implementing a template renderer in shell script. The template variables are represented in a template by @VAR_NAME@ and their values are defined in a separate shell script.

Sample code:

```
# template variables values
CONTACT_EMAIL="myemail"
CONTACT_NAME="myname"
VARS="CONTACT_EMAIL CONTACT_NAME"

TEMPLATE_FILEPATH="mytemplate.txt"

# template renderer
set -x
SEDARGS=
for VAR in $VARS; do
     SEDARGS+=" -e \"s,@$VAR@,${!VAR},\""
done
sed -r $SEDARGS $TEMPLATE_FILEPATH
```

sed command executed by shell and printed by it because of "set -x":

```
+ sed -r -e '"s,@CONTACT_EMAIL@,myemail,"' -e '"s,@CONTACT_NAME@,myname,"' mytemplate.txt
```

sed output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

I know the single quotes around each sed expression are causing this non-intuitive error message, but I do not know why they are added.

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) ... I mean *possible*, and I hope the link helps.

Comment: `SEDARGS+=" -e 's,@$VAR@,${!VAR},' "` might work. Interesting idea! good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have embedded quotes inside your `SEDARGS` variable. These are NOT removed when the command is executed. To remove them, you need to call the interpreter again, which you can do using `eval`. For example:

```
eval sed -r $SEDARGS $TEMPLATE_FILEPATH
```

You may need to play around that some more (adding quotes, etc.).

Comment: That worked, thanks! This is very tricky. I assume that the Linux shell first parses the quotes and then performs variable substitution?

Comment: Yes. It has to do it in that order, otherwise the single quotes wouldn't stop the variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes aren't part of the actual arguments. They get added by your shell for the output caused by `set -x` only.

Why would the shell do that? So that you can use that output to re-run exactly what was executed during the script execution. As you correctly noticed, they are needed to protect the `"` that came from `SEDARGS` *content* (i.e., the *inner* ones, in your script escaped as `\"`).